# ListAnimate with controls like a slideshow

Tags: image, wolfram-mathematica

This may be an abuse of ListAnimate but I'm using it to flip through a bunch of images.
When there are few enough images I can grab the slider with the mouse and flip back and forth among the images easily enough.

But when there are too many it's very tricky to flip through them one by one.
Is there a way to simply use the arrow keys (or whatever keys) to flip forward and backward through the images, kind of like a slideshow?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple keyboard controlled slideshow:

```
SlideShow[list_List] := 
 With[{len = Length[list]}, DynamicModule[{pos = 1}, 
      EventHandler[Dynamic[Pane[list[[pos]]]], 
                {"RightArrowKeyDown" :> (pos = Mod[pos + 1, len, 1]), 
                 "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (pos = Mod[pos - 1, len, 1]), 
                 "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (pos = 1), 
                 "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (pos = len)}]]]
```

Then you control the slideshow by selecting the output and using the arrow keys:
right=forward, left=back, up=first, down=last,

For example:

```
SlideShow[{"a","b","c","d"}]
```

Some example pictures:

```
pics = ExampleData /@ ExampleData["TestImage"][[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]

SlideShow@pics
```

(* Imagine a screen capture here *)

This can be dressed up to give it a frame, buttons, etc...

Comment: Simple and it works. Wonder if one could 'scroll' though a block of text the same way. (Wishing for two-column layouts...)

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that SlideView or FlipView will do exactly what I want!
(Except that neither of them seem to offer keyboard controls, which would be very nice.)

Comment: I wonder if you can set up a [DynamicModule wormhole](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#1497695040) to retroactively add an `EventHandler` functionality to `SlideShow`....

Comment: the docs say "it is possible to link up arbitrary existing DynamicModules, but doing so is tricky, and beyond the scope of this document." (There's a small discussion of it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/m2tEEaZG8wU)) Maybe this is worth a question on its own.

Answer (score 2):

The following also works:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 1},
 EventHandler[SlideView[{a, b, c, d}, Dynamic[i]],
  {"RightArrowKeyDown" :> (i = Min[i + 1, 4]),
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (i = Max[i - 1, 1])}]]
```

Comment: Oh yeah... for some reason I thought there wasn't a second argument for `SlideView`